# is there any way to trigger a function everytime a user enter in a product of woocommerce's backend?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to have a function that triggers everytime a user (backend) of wordpress, comes into the admin area and enter to a product post (to modify it or similar) .

I want to know the user and so on... (I have that part already)

What I dont know is how to call that function. I am using woocommerce.

So far what Ive tried is this:

```
function product_cpt_columns($columns) {

        echo "test";
    }
    add_filter('manage_product_posts_columns' , 'product_cpt_columns');
```

Refered at this link http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_edit-post_type_columns

But is not working.. I am inserting this in an activated plugin main file. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Ideas? Sure! Hook into the `save_post` action and check for the post type `product`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong hook, as far as I can tell. [`save_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) is triggered every time a post is created or updated.

Or to be more specific, you can use the [`save_post_product`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0.1/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3493) which will only fire when product posts are created or updated.

**For example:**

```
add_action( 'save_post_product', 'so_27303738_save_product' );
function so_27303738_save_product( $post_id ){
  if( has_term( 'bacon', 'product_cat', $post_id ) ){
     // do something special if the product category is bacon
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you! is there any way to know the category of the saved (or future to save) post? I checked the request and is not sending any category

Comment: Both hooks that I mentioned will pass a `$post_id` variable to attached functions. You can use the `$post_id` to check almost anything related to the post. See also [`get_the_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms), [`get_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term), and [`has_term()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term).